# Wordpress. Почему перестает работать ACF на странице рубрики, если у неё есть записи?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую плагин для Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields
Создал группу полей для страницы рубрики. Вывод стандартный
`<?php the_field('cat_description'); ?>`

Настроил рубрику, добавляю первый пост к ней и вывод ACF перестает работать. 
То есть как только у рубрики появляются записи, ACF перестает передавать данные. Как только убираю в посте галочку рубрики, всё снова работает.

Цикл вывода постов в category.php исключил, убрал его со страницы, и ситуация не изменилась.

Пытался пересоздать группу полей заново и прописать вывод и значения, но не помогает. Тема самописная.

Кто подскажет, как состояние рубрики (есть/нет записей) может влиять на работу плагина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для вывода полей таксономии (в данном случае, это категории) нужно передать соответствующий параметр:

```
<?php the_field('cat_description', get_queried_object()); ?>
```

Полная документация: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/